# mongodb aggregation on nested string JSON object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents in MongoDB that stores json object in String format, the address field as below the example. How can I use aggregations to convert the json string into object and also the other fields remain untouched?

```
{   
    "name": "John",
    "contact": 123456789,
    "address": "{"building_name": "abc", "block": 40, "street_name": "test street", "postal_code":123456}"
    "gender": "m"
}
```

The aggregations I used to convert json string into object is as below, but the other fields such as the name, contact will be removed too. How can I only convert the address field, but not the name and contact fields.

```
{
    $project:{
        "address":{
            $function:{
                "body": "function(address){ return JSON.parse(address) }",
                "args":[
                    "$address"
                ],
                "lang": "js"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$addFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) instead of [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), If you don't want to remove the other fields

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
     "address": {
          $function: {
             "body": "function(address){ return JSON.parse(address) }",
              "args": [
                "$address"
              ],
            "lang": "js"
        }
     }
  }
})
```

[MONGODB PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/obDG7BRajRs)